# Parallel optimization with extra parameters (fmincon) using for loop and if then statements

Tags: matlab, if-statement, for-loop

I am trying to do parallel processing optimization (fmincon) using for loops for each a,b=0:.01:1 includes if then statement because I have a normalized condition which is a^2+b^2+c^2=1 then c=sqrt(1-a^2-b^2). I am getting confused on the coding.
I tried this code (see below), but it could not work.
**I wrote a file objfun.m.**

```
function f= objfun (x,a,b,c)
    load test.mat a b
    p1=-sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(4)-x(3))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2))+sin(((x(4)-x(3))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2)-((x(2)-x(1))/2))+sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2)-((x(4)-x(3))/2))+sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(4)-x(3))/2)-((x(6)-x(5))/2));
    p2=sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(4)-x(3))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2))+sin(((x(4)-x(3))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2)-((x(2)-x(1))/2))-sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2)-((x(4)-x(3))/2))+sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(4)-x(3))/2)-((x(6)-x(5))/2));
    p3=sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(4)-x(3))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2))-sin(((x(4)-x(3))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2)-((x(2)-x(1))/2))+sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2)-((x(4)-x(3))/2))+sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(4)-x(3))/2)-((x(6)-x(5))/2));
    p4=sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(4)-x(3))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2))+sin(((x(4)-x(3))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2)-((x(2)-x(1))/2))+sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(6)-x(5))/2)-((x(4)-x(3))/2))-sin(((x(2)-x(1))/2)+((x(4)-x(3))/2)-((x(6)-x(5))/2));

    f=p1+2*a*c*p2+2*a*b*p3+2*b*c*p4;
```

**I wrote the main file**

```
%x=[x(1),x(2),x(3),x(4),x(5),x(6)]; % angles;
clc;
p=0:0.1:1;q=0:0.1:1;
for m=1:length(p)
for n=1:length(q)
    a=p(m);b=q(n);
    if a^2+b^2+c^2=1 Then c=sqrt(1-a*a-b*b) 
    save test.mat a b
    lb=[0,0,0,0,0,0];
    ub=[pi,pi,pi,pi,pi,pi];
    x0=[pi/8;pi/3;0.7*pi;pi/2;.5;pi/4];
    [x,fval]=fmincon(@objfun,x0,[],[],[],[],lb,ub);
    clear a b
    opt_val(m,n)=fval;
    end 
end
end
```

What I have to do to make this code work? I need some help on structuring the main file please .

Comment: Which error message do you get?

Comment: Error: File: main.m Line: 7 Column: 23
The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

As your error message states, there is a problem with this line in the main code:

```
if a^2+b^2+c^2=1 Then c=sqrt(1-a*a-b*b)
```

There are a few problems here. First, this is not valid MATLAB syntax for an if clause. For the correct syntax, see [the documentation](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html).

Secondly, a single `=` in MATLAB is an *assignment* operator, not a comparison. For testing equality, you need to use [`==`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eq.html), for example: `a==b` will produce `true` if `a` is equal to `b` and `false` otherwise.